Thread 2: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102816584) How to resolve this error
Could you explain how and why it acts like this and if you have some exact sources also please share.
I am following Youtube tutorial where he used Rick and Morty API, so I want to show Episode list and in each cell I want to display episode name and character list (this one I have to fetch from the list of character URLs). SO I am having trouble with fetching the character list
If I use DispatchGroup, I can easily fetch my initial episodes with characters of each episode, but when scroll down and trigger additional fetch it stops working.
protocol RMEpisodeViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func initialEpisodesFetched()
    func didLoadAdditionalCharacters(with newIndexpath: [IndexPath])
}

class RMEpisodeViewModel: NSObject {
    private var episodeViewModels: [RMEpisodeViewCellViewModel] = []
    private var info: RMInfo?
    private var loadingMore = false
    weak var delegate: RMEpisodeViewDelegate?

    func fetchEpisodes(episodesURL: URL? = nil) {

        var rmRequest: RMRequest = .listEpisodesRequests
        if let episodesURL = episodesURL {
            guard let request = RMRequest(url: episodesURL) else { return }
            rmRequest = request
        }

        RMService.shared.execute(
            rmRequest, 
            expecting: RMResponse<RMEpisode>.self)
        { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                self.info = response.info
                self.setupEpisodeViewModel(episodes: response.results) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let episodesURL = episodesURL {
                            let indexPath = (self.episodeViewModels.count - response.results.count ..< self.episodeViewModels.count).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
                            self.delegate?.didLoadAdditionalCharacters(with: indexPath)
                            self.loadingMore = false
                        } else {
                            self.delegate?.initialEpisodesFetched()
                        }
                        self.loadingMore = false
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                self.loadingMore = false
            }
        }
    }

    private func setupEpisodeViewModel(episodes: [RMEpisode], completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        
        for episode in episodes {
            guard let characterURLs = episode.characters else { continue }
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            fetchEpisodeCharacters(characterURLs: characterURLs) { characters in
                self.episodeViewModels.append(RMEpisodeViewCellViewModel(episode: episode, characters: characters))
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
        
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion()
        }
    }

    private func fetchEpisodeCharacters(characterURLs: [String], completion: @escaping ([RMCharacter]) -> Void) {
        var characters: [RMCharacter] = []
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        
        for urlString in characterURLs {
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { continue }
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            fetchCharacter(url: url) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let character):
                    characters.append(character)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
        
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global()) {
            completion(characters)
        }
    }

    private func fetchCharacter(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<RMCharacter, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let rmRequest = RMRequest(url: url) else {
            completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "Invalid URL", code: 0, userInfo: nil)))
            return
        }
        RMService.shared.execute(rmRequest, expecting: RMCharacter.self, completion: completion)
    }
}
extension RMEpisodeViewModel: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        episodeViewModels.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: RMEpisodeViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? RMEpisodeViewCell else {
            fatalError("Cell type mismatch")
        }
        cell.configure(viewModel: episodeViewModels[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        return CGSize(width: bounds.width - 24, height: 0.2 * bounds.height)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        guard let footer = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: RMFooterLoadingCollectionReusableView.identifier, for: indexPath) as? RMFooterLoadingCollectionReusableView else {
            fatalError("Footer type mismatch")
        }
        info?.next != nil ? footer.startAnimating() : footer.stopAnimating()
        
        return footer
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: info?.next != nil ? 100 : 0)
    }
}

extension RMEpisodeViewModel: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let totalLength = (episodeViewModels.count - 1) * 150
        if Int(offset) - totalLength > 0, !loadingMore, info?.next != nil {
            loadingMore = true
            guard let url = URL(string: info!.next!) else {
                loadingMore = false
                return
            }
            fetchEpisodes(episodesURL: url)
        }
    }
}

Screen shot of the implementation with DispatchGroup
Thread 8 Queue : com.apple.CFNetwork.CacheDB-write (serial)
Thread 9 Queue : com.apple.NSURLSession-delegate (serial)
Thread 10 Queue : com.apple.NSURLSession-work (serial)
and now This code do not use DispatchGroup
final class RMEpisodeViewModel: NSObject {
    
    weak var delegate: RMEpisodeViewDelegate?
    
    var info: RMInfo? = nil
    var episodeViewModels: [RMEpisodeViewCellViewModel] = []
    var loadingMore = false
    
    func fetchEpisodes(episodesURL: URL? = nil) {
        var rmRequest: RMRequest = .listEpisodesRequests
        if let episodesURL = episodesURL {
            guard let request = RMRequest(url: episodesURL) else { return }
            rmRequest = request
        }
        RMService.shared.execute(rmRequest, expecting: RMResponse<RMEpisode>.self, completion: {
            [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                self.info = response.info
                self.setupEpisodeViewModel(episodes: response.results) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let episodesURL = episodesURL {
                            let indexPath = (self.episodeViewModels.count - response.results.count ..< self.episodeViewModels.count).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}
                            self.delegate?.didLoadAdditionalCharacters(
                                with: indexPath)
                        } else {
                            self.delegate?.initialEpisodesFetched()
                        }
                        self.loadingMore = false
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }
    
    func setupEpisodeViewModel(episodes: [RMEpisode], completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        let startCount = self.episodeViewModels.count
        episodes.forEach { episode in
            guard let characterURLs = episode.characters else { return }
            let characters = fetchEpisodeCharacters(characterURLs: characterURLs)
            
            episodeViewModels.append(RMEpisodeViewCellViewModel(episode: episode, characters: characters))
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: startCount + indexPaths.count, section: 0)
            indexPaths.append(indexPath)
        }
        completion()
    }

    private func fetchEpisodeCharacters(characterURLs: [String]) -> [RMCharacter] {
        var characters: [RMCharacter] = []
        characterURLs.forEach { url in
            guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
            fetchCharacter(url: url) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let character):
                    characters.append(character)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        return characters
    }

    private func fetchCharacter(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<RMCharacter, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let rmRequest = RMRequest(url: url) else { return }
        RMService.shared.execute(rmRequest, expecting: RMCharacter.self, completion: completion)
    }
}

Here it does not display character list for initial fetch, but for the additional fetching it works perfectly
I have used both of the ways and the results are totally different is there any way to do the fetching work in both ways

On the second one, it shouldn't work. If you add a print before switch result and before return characters it won't print the the order you think in console.

The DispatchGroup code seems correct. When it crashes like that, it usually means that you've called more times leave() than enter(). So check the code of RMService.shared.execute(rmRequest, expecting: RMCharacter.self, completion: completion) that might be wrong, calling completion() more than once.

RMService.shared.execute() this is just a simple fetching function with
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(...) {
completion()
}
task.resume()...
